# SimpleDateFormat wrong unix timestamp after parsing

Tags: java, date, timezone, simpledateformat

I'm trying to use SimpleDateFormat to convert between unix timestamp and a custom format and vice versa.
To test this vice versa converting I wrote the following testcase:

```
public class Testception extends TestCase {
    public void testTheTestOrTestception() throws ParseException {
        Date datum = new Date(649555200000L);
        SimpleDateFormat dfm = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd");
        TimeZone tZ = TimeZone.getTimeZone("Europe/Berlin");
        dfm.setTimeZone(tZ);
        String aDifferentFormat = dfm.format(datum);
        assertEquals("1990-08-02", aDifferentFormat);
        Date datum2 = dfm.parse(aDifferentFormat);
        assertEquals(649555200000L, datum2.getTime());
    }
}
```

I'm starting with an unixtimestamp (649555200000), converting it in my custom format ("1990-08-02") which is working just nicely. But unfortunately the second assert fails and instead of the expected 649555200000L the result is 649548000000L

Thanks in advance.

Cheers L0rdAli3n

Comment: How do you know that it should be 649555200000L?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It's all to do with the time zones.

You've given it midnight *UTC*, and formatted that as a date - but it was actually 2am in Berlin time.

You're then parsing that *date* which will parse to midnight on that date *in Berlin*, which is two hours earlier than your starting point. If you want to get midnight UTC back again, just set the time zone of your `SimpleDateFormat` to the UTC time zone.

Comment: Wow, fastest answer ever. And your hint with UTC was awesome. You really nailed it :) Could you quickly explain how you found out that I gave in a midnight UTC?

Comment: @L0rdAli3n: I printed out `new Date(649555200000L)` and looked at the result :) (As for fast - that was over 5 minutes! Apologies for the tardiness...)

Comment: How did you printed out new Date(649555200000L). Because I surely looked at the date-object more than once via toString and toGMTString?!?

Comment: @L0rdAli3n: I just used `toString`, knowing that the result would be in my local time zone.

Comment: Thanks a lot. With your explanation the toString-output makes perfect sense :)

Answer (score 1):

There's nothing wrong with the code, just the input assumption.

649555200000L is 2 in the morning in Berlin on August 2nd 1990.  The actual result is the correct value for midnight in Berlin, which is what java will give you when you parse a date-only string pattern into a java.util.Date.

Comment: Thanks for the quick response. Your answer is perfectly right, bu Jon Skeet also provide a working fix. So I accapted his post as answer, but you also got an upvote, well done! :)